# Host doesn't support .Net Framework v4

Tags: c#, silverlight, .net-4.0

I have developed a small application using silverlight with .Net framework v4 which was hosted internally. Now I was asked to deploy it to the web host of my company. I found that the web host (NetworkSolutions.com) doesn't support v4! ..

How can I go about solving this issue? .. i mean is there a way to use v2 instead .. i expect this will break my code badly.. (given that I'm also using RIA services (wcf))

It can be a noob question but i'm sorry i'm not that experienced with web hosting. I have always hosted my applications internally.

Comment: have you spoken to your hosting company about getting .net 4 support?

Comment: I'm sure there's a lesson to be learnt by all .NET developers from this...!

Comment: Unlimited hosting for $27.18 a month.  If it sounds too good to be true then it invariably is.

Comment: Yes i have asked and the answer i got was " we have no idea to when we will start supporting .net 4 "

Answer (score 4):

Well, WCF came in .NET 3.5 - so if they support 3.5 you may not need to change *very* much. I suggest you:

- Check that the hosting company supports .NET 3.5
- Change the target of your project to .NET 3.5
- Fix up any errors locally - hopefully not too many, if you're not using *too* many .NET 4 features
- Deploy to the hosting company

Comment: I thought about that too.. but as far as i know they don't support 3.5 either! .. therefore it means i will have to use another means to connect to my DB other the ADO.NET and WCF.. annoying.. !

Comment: @aamran: It would have been helpful to say so to start with. I suggest you find out for sure. (Bear in mind that v3.5 still only uses the v2 CLR...) I would just *try* a simple no-op v3.5 project to start with.